# Tabulator.js - IE11 - "Error: Unspecified error. .."

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, tabulator

I have no idea what is wrong with this code:

```
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';

export default class Table {
 constructor(tableElement) {
   this.tableElemet = tableElement;
 }

 render(tableData, locale) {
        const self = this;
        this.table = new Tabulator(this.tableElement, {
            locale: locale,
            cellHozAlign: "right",
            columns: this.columns(),
            data: tableData,
            layout: "fitColumns",
            resizableColumns: false,
            maxHeight: "500px",
            pagination:"local",
            paginationSize: 30,
            paginationSizeSelector:[30, 50, 100, true],
            langs: this.langs(),
            downloadConfig: {
                columnGroups: true
            },
            tableBuilt: function (){
                self.modifyPagination(this.getPageMax());
            }
        });
 }

 //other functions
}
```

Im using ES6. Only on IE getting error:

```
Error: Unspecified error. { 
  [functions]: , __proto__: { }, 
  description: "Unspecified error.", 
  message: "Unspecified error.", 
  name: "Error", 
  number: -2147467259, 
  stack: "Error: Unspecified error. 
        at RowManager.prototype.adjustTableSize (tabulator.js?v32:147:7) 
        at Anonymous function ({myFilePath}", Symbol()_6.e5wrk79qtse: undefined }
```

Someone have any ideas?
I tried to display an empty table (without any parameters) - also had the same problem.
If you need more information, let me know.

Tabulator v4.9.1

Browsers: IE 11

Windows 10

Comment: In what kind of JS project you are using Tabulator.js? like Angular, ReactJS, etc. To narrow down the issue, I suggest you create a sample using a simple HTML page with Tabulator 4.9.1, see whether it works on IE 11. If the same code was used to work with IE 11 then I suggest you try to make a test with the latest version of Tabulator.js. It may help you to fix the error if there is some issue related to the Tabulator.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a regression introduced in version 4.9 that broke IE functionality, if you pull down the latest version, 4.9.3 it should work

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version helped (4.9.3), thank you Oli